# The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD. Vue.js, Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm having some problems with this message" The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.". I'm building a laravel + vue post app, but I'm not being able to make it work, I don't know if I'm missing something. This is how my template (in short) looks like:

```
<div>
    <form action="/post/create" method="POST">
</div>
```

My routes (just have 1):

```
Route::get('/post/create', [\App\Http\Controllers\PostController::class, 'create']);
```

How, can I show the added tickets in the same view, it's needed to add another route or change the get route to post?, I'm a bit new and I'm very very lost, haha.

I'm using a vue template, not a blade

Comment: What are you trying to do, create a new ticket, display a single ticket or all your tickets?

Comment: Hi, I want to add a ticket, and display all the tickets created, in the same page, or maybe in another, but I always get the same error, I have checked almost 40 post here about the same thing, but the most of them are related to blade templates, moved some things, added @csrf to vue template, and more things, but always getting the same error

Comment: This is not a blade or vue issue. Your Laravel route doesn’t support POST requested. You need to define a route that does.

Comment: Have a watch of [this video](https://youtu.be/pSYu_XNkJ98) and try fixing this yourself. If you are still stuck update your question with what you’ve changed and how you’re stuck and we’ll help debug.

Comment: @Peppermintology oh thanks for the answers, I'll watch it

Comment: No worries. Better to educate so you understand than simply give you an answer without explanation and you blindly copy.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing

Comment: @Peppermintology I have watched the video, and read a lot more, helped with som things that I didn't completely knew,next tried differents options but still not working, maybe I'm missing something that I'm not able to see, in the comments below, I posted my controller, routes and form template info, if you can, check this and give me a hint, not the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FINALLY GOT the solution /o/, It was a problem with the csrf token in vue, I have placed the meta csrf in my root blade, and added the hidden input with the csrf and is working everything. Now I just need to show the form post info in idk, in the console, a json, or in the same page. That's a new fight but, well, I have made a great progress /o/

Comment: glad, you found it working.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define post method if you using **method="POST"**

```
<div>
    <form action="/tickets/create" method="POST">
</div>

Route::post('/tickets/create', [\App\Http\Controllers\TicketController::class, 'create']);
```

Comment: Every time I try to change that to post, the entire page fail, and appear this message:
"The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.".
Maybe adding another route or another component to show can help?

Comment: @Vue-learning Routes are independent meaning you require a route for each HTTP verb you want to use. The [verb used will depend on the operation you are performing](https://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html#:~:text=The%20primary%20or%20most%2Dcommonly,but%20are%20utilized%20less%20frequently.). So you’ll need separate routes, Laravel does have a shorthand for defining them all though.

Comment: @Peppermintology bro, I found the solution after searching a lot, it was a problem with the csrf token in vue, now I can use the post and get routes (actually I'm using match bcs is the same thing), now my app is working, or at least saving the information. Now I'm trying to show the info sended in the form idk, in a space, or in the console, now this is a new fight haha, can't find a way to show everything. But at least, is was a great progress. Thanks for the info shared

Comment: @Vue-learning Well done for persisting and persevering. It sounds like it was a steep learning curve but you got there and hopefully learned a lot in the process. Now to build something great!

Comment: @Peppermintology actually using match wasn't the solution, just needed to create a new route with post, and changed the info like this:  
Route::post('/tickets/create', [\App\Http\Controllers\TicketController::class, 'store']); , next modified some extra things, and now with a dd($request->all()); in my controller store function, now this show me the info added in the form in a "new view" (is temporal by now), modified things in the form to match the info in the store function so it can be saved in the DB. Reading the most is the solution, and your info helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
Route::post('/tickets/create', [\App\Http\Controllers\TicketController::class, 'create']);
```

to

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'],'/tickets/create', [\App\Http\Controllers\TicketController::class, 'create']);
```

This is because, you are using same route for both requests. [loading the form into DOM and posting the form] .

Comment: tried that but still not working, maybe I'm missing something that I'm not able to see

Comment: I have moved some things related with the csrf token and now I can use the match route, and is working, thanks bro